# Stuck when considering a switch and while loop on adding up a sentence and characters therein

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that inputs a sentence and computes counts of chracters of various kinds.  For example,

INPUT:

Enter a sentence that ends with a'.' or '!' or '?': This* is A
samplE
sentence!

OUTPUT:

Total number of characters: 28
Number of vowels: 8
Number of newlines: 3
Number of tabs: 1
Number of spaces: 2
Number of other characters: 14

So far I have:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
char c;
int i;
    printf("Enter a sentence (ended by a '.' or '!' or '?'):\n");
    scanf("%c", &c);

while (c !='.' && c !='?' && c !='!')

switch(c)
    {
        case 'a': i++;

        case 'e': i++;

        case 'i': i++;

        case 'o': i++;

        case 'u': i++;
    }
return 0;
   }
```

In short, I need to write a program that reads a sentence, character by character, and counts the total number of characters, the
number of vowels, newline characters, tabs, spaces and all other characters. The sentence the user enters will end
with either a period, question mark, or exclamation mark. The program will not count the period, exclamation mark,
or question mark as a character.
     Can someone help me out?
// UPDATE: I need to write it using while loop and switch. I am sure things will be cascaded, but that is the requirement.

Comment: Check the C manual regarding `switch`. Each case will just "fall through" to the next without a `break` statement. So your loop will count each `a` 5 times, each `e` 4 times, etc. Also, you're only reading one character then entering your loop without reading any more. You should perhaps read the whole line into a `char` array, then go through the `char` array in your loop, one `char` at a time. Or you could read the input one character at a time with `getchar()` and stop when you see the end of line or end of sentence.

Comment: If you had a lookup table you could do `i += value[c]` where `value` is a 256 entry array that's mostly `0` but `1` for the vowels.

Comment: ... or a 256-entry array of character kinds and a 5-entry array of character counts.  Then you could do `count[kind[c]]++` without any `switch`ing at all.

Comment: In addition to @lurker 's comment, you can add a `default:` case to count "other characters".

Comment: In response to everyone's post above, I need to write it using while loop and switch. I am sure things will be cascaded, but that is the requirement. I should have posted that in my initial post, but I am now updating it.

Comment: "The program will not count the period, exclamation mark, or question mark as a character" When your program hits one of those characters, the loop terminates as the condition isn't true anymore so the stuff inside the switch case doesn't run. Remember that the condition is checked before each iteration of the loop and the loop body only executes when the condition is true. Use a do-while loop instead. There are many other problems in your code, such as the uninitialized `i` variable, the switch cases missing `break` statements, and you only reading one character at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    int end = 0;
    int vowels = 0;
    int newlines = 1;
    int tabs = 0;
    int spaces = 0;
    int others = 0;
    int total = 0;

    printf("Enter a sentence (ended by a '.' or '!' or '?'):\n");

    while(!end) {
        scanf("%c", &c);
        switch(c) {
            case '.':
            case '?':
            case '!':
                end = 1;
                break;
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
            case 'A':
            case 'E':
            case 'I':
            case 'O':
            case 'U':
                vowels++;
                break;
            case '\n':
                newlines++;
                break;
            case '\t':
                tabs++;
                break;
            case ' ':
                spaces++;
                break;
            default:
                switch(c) {
                    case 'a' ... 'z':
                    case 'A' ... 'Z':
                        others++;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    total = vowels + newlines + tabs + spaces + others;
    printf("Total number of characters: %d\n", total);
    printf("Number of vowels: %d\n", vowels);
    printf("Number of newlines: %d\n", newlines);
    printf("Number of tabs: %d\n", tabs);
    printf("Number of spaces: %d\n", spaces);
    printf("Number of other characters: %d\n", others);

    return 0;
}
```